# file_get_contents messing up web page

Tags: php, curl, proxy, file-get-contents

I have configured a simple php proxy file:

```
 echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

and it seems to work with most pages(cnn.com, foxnews.com, twitter, facebook ...) but for some reason it completely messes up others, it enough to compare [www.index.hr](http://www.index.hr) and http://phppetar.heliohost.org/proxy.php?url=http://www.index.hr to know what i mean ...

i have also noticed that logo image for google.com doesn't work

does anyone knows what could be the problem?

P.S i have tried curl but with same results ..

Comment: File resources use relative paths.

Comment: CSS files aren't loaded properly

Comment: Yeah, the css files are loaded from their relative paths, so you can't access them from your website.

Comment: You might want to sanitize the input as it stands a user can pull files from your server.

Comment: so in other words there is nothing i can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `<base>` html tag so that all relative URLs will be taken from the original site. On the other hand, they will see in their logs your URL in referrer field, but I'm not sure if that matters to you.

Comment: @BlackRaider When the question is solved and you don't need further assistance on the topic, consider accepting the best question as a solution. This will mark it as "solved" and others won't waste their time looking in thinking you need further help.